# I have problem when I config a distributed always on availability group

Tags: sql-server, high-availability, disaster-recovery, alwayson, sql-server-administration

I have 4 virtual machines with SQL Server 2017

Two machines IP are `x.x.190.5` and `x.x.190.6`; these machine have first always on availability group (AVG01)

And the other machines IP `x.x.189.1` and `x.x.189.2`; these machine have second always on availability group (AVG02)

Now I want to config distribute always on between these always on

All configuration pass successful , but at the end in distributed always on the second availability group have a red multiple icon and DAVG have not work!!!!

And always on dashboard have object reference error when i try to check it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem

we configure listeners on port 1433 and endpoints on port 5022

when we config distribute always on we write listener address with port 1433 but it is wrong we must be write listener address + endpoint port